# HTTP link in custom close reason

Tags: bug, close-reasons, hyperlinks

I was looking at the custom close reasons and noticed that the custom close reason for product or service recommendations includes a link to

```
http://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
```

Obviously that is an http link.  It redirects to https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ but I think it's supposed to go there without a redirect.

There was a similar question on the Code Review meta where the problem was escalated to the Stack Exchange staff to fix.  They said to post more links like that if anyone saw one or more.  I'm following that template here.